# Best web ad providers for tracking exact income per user/ad?

Tags: advertising, url-shortening

I’m developing a service where the user will earn “credits” on my service by viewing advertisements. That being said, as such I need to be able to track the exact income they’re earning me so I can then add that to their account (credits will allow them usage into my service, they’re not getting the money or anything).

I was originally using Linkvertise where I would generate a link, then they’d be redirected to a different route on my site where the income for the link would then be checked and added to their account. This is because fortunately Linkvertise offers the ability to view the exact income for each link in USD.

However, as of a couple months ago, Linkvertise added an update which limits the amount of links a user can go through for free to 3 per day (unless you purchase their subscription, which is customer based, not publisher based).

That being said, I need a new solution. Any ideas for services that offer exact income stats?

I’ve tried similar link sites like work.ink but they unfortunately don’t offer the same income features per link